# Assign coordinates to each picture(tif)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I have a mini project to do which is to assign coordinates to each tiff image and later covert these images to ECW format.  Im using Qgis 216 Nobedo. I have a txt file with the names of pictures and coordinates +pictures themselves. 
Is there a way I could assign coordinates to each picture on QGIS?

Comment: what are these images? are you georeferencing aerial photos or something similar?

Comment: Thank you  for reply. I want to add spatial reference to each tiff.  I do not have any ground control points apart from coordinates of each picture (which I assume is the centre of picture)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a worldfile file - a .tfw file in your case, which is a text file with a tfw extension. It's quite simple, but you need to know some info on the pictures : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

> The generic meaning of the six parameters in a world file (as defined by Esri[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file)) are:
>
> - Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel
> - Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis
> - Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis
> - Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative[3]
> - Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
> - Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel
>
> Example: Original falknermap.jpg is 800×600 pixels (map not shown). Its world file is falknermap.jgw and contains:
>
> 32.0
>
> 0.0
>
> 0.0
>
> -32.0
>
> 691200.0
>
> 4576000.0

Or you could georeference those pictures with the georeferencer : https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/how-to-georeference-a-map-in-qgis/

Comment: So if i create a tfw wordfile   for a picture ,QGIS would understand that this picture has a spacial reference?

Comment: Sort of. The worldfile gives an equivalence of pixel based coordinate system to real world projection. You still have to tell QGIS what projection coordinates you're using.